# Cannot stat date: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, centos7

I have a script that runs daily to add/commit/push to github. I'm trying to change the commit message to the size of the commit, which will always be only 1 file, in the format of `<date>.html`.

I can reference the date using `date "+%Y%m%d".html`, which returns a valid filename in the terminal. However, when I try to stat it using `stat --printf="%s" date\ "+\%Y\%m\%d".html`, it returns the error `stat: cannot stat ‘date +\\%Y\\%m\\%d.html’: No such file or directory`.

I understand that it is not executing my date as a command. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `date ...` part as a *literal* argument, not a result of Bash command, so you must wrap it into the `$()` construction.

```
stat --printf="%s" $(date "+%Y%m%d.html")
```

This will work.